# How to create dropdown list in addin using VBA in PowerPoint 2007?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I created one code for addin in which my all code runs at one time after clicking of one button. But now I want to create dropdown list in which I can select any one event for run.

Below is my code for button:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim oToolbar As CommandBar
    Dim oButton As CommandBarButton
    Dim MyToolbar As String

    ' Give the toolbar a name
    MyToolbar = "Test"

    On Error Resume Next
    ' so that it doesn't stop on the next line if the toolbar's already there

    ' Create the toolbar; PowerPoint will error if it already exists
    Set oToolbar = CommandBars.Add(Name:=MyToolbar, _
        Position:=msoBarFloating, Temporary:=True)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          ' The toolbar's already there, so we have nothing to do
          Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

    ' Now add a button to the new toolbar
    Set oButton = oToolbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)

    ' And set some of the button's properties
    With oButton
         .DescriptionText = "Test_dist"
          'Tooltip text when mouse if placed over button
         .Caption = "Trial"
         'Text if Text in Icon is chosen
         .OnAction = "TEST"
          'Runs the Sub Button1() code when clicked
         .Style = msoButtonIconAndWrapCaptionBelow
          ' Button displays as icon, not text or both
         .FaceId = 1885
         .TooltipText = "Test your presentation"
    End With

    ' You can set the toolbar position and visibility here if you like
    ' By default, it'll be visible when created
    oToolbar.Top = 50
    oToolbar.Left = 150
    oToolbar.Visible = True

NormalExit:

    Exit Sub   ' so it doesn't go on to run the errorhandler code

Errorhandler:
     'Just in case there is an error

     Resume NormalExit:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim oDropdown As CommandBarComboBox    
Set oDropdown = oToolbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlDropdown)
With oDropdown
    .Clear
    .AddItem ("This")
    .AddItem ("That")
    .AddItem ("The Other Thing")
    ' default it to first item selected
    .ListIndex = 1
    .OnAction = "ProcessDropdown"
End With
```

And this to handle the change event of the dropdown:

```
Sub ProcessDropdown()
    MsgBox CommandBars("Test").Controls(2).Text
End Sub
```